# if condition inside program not working

Tags: php, android

This is a simple project based on android-php-mysql connection using xamp server.Here iam trying to update the query,and its updating successfully in server database,and getting php respond as granted,but if condition in my program is not working,what will i do?? please help me..Here is my code!!
thank you in advance

```
btt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


    try{
            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.45/doctorphp/status.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date",Datetxt.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            System.out.println("Response : " + response);
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                    tvView.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);


            }    });

            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Granted")){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(UserPage.this,"Granted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });   
                Intent intent=new Intent(UserPage.this, token.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                  showAlert();    
            }
        }  
        catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error:"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }   



    }
});
```

Comment: Did you debug it goes in if or not?

Comment: what are you getting in `response` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..hope it works

```
if(response.toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Granted")){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(UserPage.this,"Granted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });   
    Intent intent=new Intent(UserPage.this, token.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: sorry...its not working,it is dairectly going to else block of my program without executing if block

Comment: Then you should first check what is your response.

Comment: @AshikAshok pls accept as ans n upvote it if this ans is helpfull for u buddy :)..

Comment: @SweetWisher  i think that will not work for string comparison..my condition was rite i think.. :)

Answer (score 0):

please initialize
public static String response="";

response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);